# The API key in use does not allow this request XCode error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

App record request failed with error: "AppsService: ResponseErrors (1): Error status: 403, code: FORBIDDEN_ERROR, title: 'This request is forbidden for security reasons', detail: 'The API key in use does not allow this request'

Unable to publish react-native app on testflight (It was uploading fine before some days).

I am using XCode 14 for publishing apps. 3 days before i uploaded new version `1.0(9)`. Now I am trying for new version but it shows error (i had tried with version `1.0(10)` and `2.0(1)`)

Please write why this problem occurs and how to deal with this problem?

Steps i followed to upload the build:

[Step1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd4Mg.png)

[Step2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWFRt.png)

[Step3 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EaZ6.png)

[Step4 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzrid.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The development team you have chosen in Xcode may not have the appropriate permissions.

To address this issue, follow these steps in Xcode:

1. Open Xcode.
2. Select your build target.
3. Navigate to the "Signing & Capabilities" tab.
4. Verify that the correct team is selected.
5. Check the permissions of the team in App Store Connect.